# Is my proof of $\pi$’s irrationality correct?

Tags: irrational-numbers, pi

$1.$ Viète's formula for $\pi$ is easy to derive without trigonometry or calculus.  Starting with a square inscribed in a circle of unit diameter, the number of sides of the inscribed polygon is repeatedly doubled.
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi%C3%A8te%27s_formula

$2.$ Viète's formula (before taking the limit as $k$ goes to infinity) gives the perimeter of  a $2^{k+1}$-sided regular polygon inscribed in a circle of unit diameter.

$3.$ Because the square of a rational number is rational, the square root of an irrational number is irrational.  So, working from right to left in the nested square roots of Viète's formula, the perimeters of ALL the polygons are irrational.

$4.$ As $k$ becomes very large, the perimeter of the polygon converges to $\pi$.  Therefore $\pi$ is irrational.

Comment: No. The limit of a sequence of irrational numbers can be rational.

Comment: Well, I was going to say the same thing.  The only thing to add is, for example, $a_n = 1-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}$ for $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$. Or more simply, $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}$ (since $0$ is rational).

Comment: Thanks Michael.  Yes, I had thought about your counterexample where a_n is irrational for all n, yet the limit is rational.  That happens because the irrational term gets very tiny.  The same thing happens with the sides of the polygons: the limiting length of a side is 0.  On each step, the side-length is slightly larger than half of the side-length for the previous step.  But the number of sides doubles on each step, so you get: (a large rational number of sides)x(a tiny irrational side length) = 3.14…

Comment: Thanks, Lord Shark (Commenter 2).  Will this fix it?:
Let P_k be the irrational perimeter of the 2^(k+1)-sided polygon.
pi cannot be a finite string of decimal digits because there will always be a P_k > (that finite string).
pi cannot be a repeating decimal because P_k converges to pi but never repeats.
Therefore pi is irrational.

Comment: No, it will not fix it.

Comment: I don’t understand, Robert.  If  you ask for a value of pi correct to a trillion decimal places, there exists an irrational P_k that will give it to you.  Therefore there is no rational value of pi shorter than a trillion digits.  There is no limit on the number of correct digits you can ask for.  Can you have a rational number with an infinite number of non-repeating digits?

Comment: @stephenbarrett: I ask for a value of $0$ "correct to a trillion decimal places". There definitely is an irrational (say $\sqrt{2}/k$ with a large $k$) that will give it to me. Are you saying this implies $0$ is irrational?

Comment: Thanks metamorphy.   In my reply to Michael, I noted that the side-length of the polygons also have a limiting length of zero.  When the side-length is multiplied by the number of sides to get the perimeter, however, this dilution effect is counteracted so that the limiting perimeter is not zero.  I think that you and others on this site are trying to tell me is that, even though the perimeters are irrational, I must consider the possibility that they might be converging to a rational number with an extremely long decimal representation, which either terminates or begins a repeat pattern.